# dig all txt records

Tags: domain-name-system, dig

When I run the `dig` command, I only get one txt record:

```
adriano@vm ~  dig swisspass.ch txt                                                                                   ✔  4501  14:25:36

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.13-Ubuntu <<>> swisspass.ch txt
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47817
;; flags: qr rd ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1280
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;swisspass.ch.                  IN      TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION:
swisspass.ch.           900     IN      TXT     "v=spf1  include:spf2.sbb.ch include:spf.mandrillapp.com include:inx.ch include:amazonses.com include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all"

;; Query time: 20 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Feb 22 14:25:39 STD 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 186
```

But if i check with an online tool (for example [dig from google](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#TXT/)) I get more results:
[image: more results]

What parameter should I add to my command to show ALL the txt records?

***UPDATE***: I formatted the output to show less informations, sorry

Comment: Which version of `dig` you use? Please, include a complete output of dig; what you show certainly isn't an output of dig from ISC's `bind-tools`.

Comment: I formatted the informations of the output, sorry

Comment: The combination of the warning message *WARNING: recursion requested but not available* and no `aa` (authoritative answer) flag is a bit curious. (Why is there an answer at all in this case?)

Comment: try to check if `192.168.1.1` is faulty by using another DNS server, for example, try `dig swisspass.ch txt @8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that your local DNS server (192.168.1.1) is somehow trimming the results.

You can try to query the google DNS servers with your dig utility and see if the output would be different compared to your local DNS server:
dig @8.8.8.8 -t txt swisspass.ch

What about if you use `host'?
host -t txt swisspass.ch 8.8.8.8

Comment: +1, I agree that the problem appears to be with whatever `192.168.1.1` is, rather than the domain in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I logged out of my company's VPN and got all the txt records.
Sorry I didn't check this before, anyway thank you for your help.